# How can I access value of tuple?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to know how can I access the value from the following output:

```
output "backend_tg_arn" {
  value = var.backend_tg_needed ? aws_lb_target_group.backend_tg[*].arn : null
}
```

It is generated with the following code:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "backend_tg" {
  count       = var.backend_tg_needed ? 1 : 0
  name        = "${var.client_code}-${var.environment}-backend-tg"
  port        = var.backend_port
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = var.backend_target_type
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
}
```

The output from above is passed to another module as variable:

```
   backend_tg_arn = module.network.backend_tg_arn
```

and I'm trying to assign it to default action for alb listener:

```
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = var.backend_tg_arn
  }
}
```

Getting error:

> var.backend_tg_arn is tuple with 1 element
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "target_group_arn": string required.

I am struggling how can I access this `arn` value... it should be done with some kind of loop but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are always setting a count of 1 so you can instead just output the first element if it's created:

```
output "backend_tg_arn" {
  value = var.backend_tg_needed ? aws_lb_target_group.backend_tg[0].arn : null
}
```

Comment: Again Rocksteady to the rescue - thank you. Suppose I'm outputting with `[*]` so few elements. How can I later retrieve them out later?

Comment: You would need to index them specifically where you use them. So output a list and then consume it and index appropriately with `backend_tg_arn = module.network.backend_tg_arns[5]` to access the 6th ARN in the list of `backend_tg_arns`.

Comment: Got it. That is for one value at time. If I need all of them at once, for example, subnets made by:
`output "private_subnets" {
  value = aws_subnet.private[*].id
}`
then I need to use for example this kind of loop or something else?
`subnets          = [for subnet in data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.private_subnets : subnet]`